# Cannot display popup with validation error(s)

Tags: javascript

Goal:
To enable display a pop up if validation was correct or failure.

Problem:

> Somehow it doesn't want to make a
> validation of the password.

I tried using Firebug but It can't make debugging for this code for some reason.

Before creating this validation I had this code before:

```
function validation() {
      if (mittXHRobjekt.readyState == 4)          
      alert("Okey");
}
```

After doing more improvement by adding validation, the `readyState` don't work properly. All I did was to improve the function validation only.

---

The current code with validation is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var mittXHRobjekt = null;

      function skapaXHRobjekt() {
          try {
              XHRobjekt = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
          } catch (err1) {
              try { 
                  XHRobjekt = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              } catch (err2) {
                  try { 
                      XHRobjekt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                  } catch (err3) {
                      XHRobjekt = false;
                  }
              }
          }
          return XHRobjekt;
      }

      function validation() {
          if (mittXHRobjekt.readyState == 4) {

              if (window.document.frmPassword.txtPassword.value == mittXHRobjekt.responseText) {
                  alert("Correct password");
              }
              else {
                  alert("Wrong password");
              }
          }

          alert("no ready state 4");
      }

      function test(url) {
          mittXHRobjekt = skapaXHRobjekt();
          if (mittXHRobjekt) {
              mittXHRobjekt.onreadystatechange = validation;
              mittXHRobjekt.open("GET", url);
              mittXHRobjekt.send(null);
          }
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="frmPassword">
        <input name="txtPassword" type="password" />
        <input name="btnPassword" type="button" value="Evaluation" onclick="test('password.txt')" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be using jQuery. You're not, and there's wayyyyyyyyyyyy too much code, so I'm not going to help you. www.jquery.com and try again.

Comment: Does it just say "no ready state 4"? Does it say something and then that?

Comment: Does your code able to complete xhr request? Check network tab.